# Path attribute of Cookie is not affecting for subsequent requests

Tags: rest, cookies, path, subdomain

I have a REST web service which sends a cookie in the response. 
REST URL looks like
http://localhost:8080/myfoo/service/v1/acc/login

In my java code I have set cookie like below

```
 Response.ok(entity).cookie(new NewCookie("JSESSIONID", "12344", "/", "localhost", null, -1, false));
```

When I see the response header of the web service, cookie header looks like below

```
"JSESSIONID=12344;Domain=localhost;Path="/";Version=1"
```

But, when I make request to another path of same domain like below

http://localhost:8080/mybar/service/v1/acc/profile

cookies are not sent in the request.

So, when I viewed cookies in browser store (using content settings) I saw below entry for the cookie.

```
Name:   JSESSIONID
Content: 12344
Domain: localhost
Path:   /myfoo/service/v1/acc/login
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Wednesday, July 13, 2016 at 5:04:40 PM
Expires:    When the browsing session ends
```

So, if you notice, path attribute of cookie in browser store is different than what REST service had responded with. Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: In other words, I am unable to override default "path" attribute value of cookie

Answer (score 1):

After a long research I found the root cause. The issue was with cxf library 3.1.6. While converting cookie objects to headers, it quotes special characters.
Hence it was quoting / set in java code to "/" in the Set-Cookie header. But browser sees "/" as invalid and sets the path to current path.

But, 3.1.7-SNAPSHOT has fix for this. 
After I update my cxf library to above said version, the issue is resolved.

If we do not want to update the library, we can manually set the Set-Cookie header as an alternative solution.

Here is the reference:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6862

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue. Below is the usecase and details.

Using Jetty based Docker image, where I am trying to set cookie request (`/root/test/testing`) as below.

```
NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("Name", "Value", "/", "", 1, null, -1, null, false,false);
```

The cookie is made available to request which fall in same root context (`/root/test/test1`, `/root/test/test2`).

I want the cookie to be available to all the request in root. Some example request below.

```
/root/user/getdetails
/root/work/getworkdetails
```